# Invalid attempt to read when no data is present VB

Tags: mysql, vb.net, loops

> I get this error :Invalid attempt when no data is present.It says that line 39 and 198 are the causes of this error

**LINE 39**

```
Sub loadstudent()

    lvstudent.Items.Clear()
        While RD.Read
            With lvstudent.Items.Add(RD(1), 0)
                .SubItems.Add(RD(5)) '48
                .SubItems.Add(RD(0))
            End With
        End While
End Sub
```

**LINE 198:**

```
 sSql = "Select * from tblstudentprof where status='ACTIVE' "
    execSQL(sSql, False)
    loadstudent()
```

> I also used looping to count the selected items in a listview and move it to tblstudentprof which is connected to line 148 and line 39.

```
 Private Sub btnmove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnmove.Click
    Dim ctr, count, minus As Integer
    ctr = lvstudent.Items.Count - 1
    While ctr >= 0
        If lvstudent.Items(ctr).Checked = True Then
            sSql1 = "Update tblstudentprof set secid='" & txtsecid.Text & "',yrlevelid='" & txtyrlevelid.Text & _
                "',remarks='ENLISTED' where studid ='" & lvstudent.Items(ctr).SubItems(2).Text & "'"
            execSQL1(sSql1, True)
            ctr -= 1
        End If
    End While
    count = lvstudent.Items.Count
    minus = count - ctr1
    If minus > 0 Then
        MsgBox("There is/are " & minus & "updated students sections.")

    Else
        MsgBox("Successfully updated students sections.")

    End If
```

Comment: *Insert all previous comments about SQL Parameters, concatenating values into strings for SQL and how a DGV would be simpler and more appropriate than a ListView* plus: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: You shouldn't use concatenating string with SQL. This is a very bad practice that can lead to an injection attack.